# Getting the Average in ROWS c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a sql server database with table. These are

```
1stAP_TB, 2ndAP_TB, 3rdAP_TB, 4thAP_TB, 1steng_TB, 2ndeng_TB, 3rdeng_TB, 
4theng_TB
```

all in them are in row. The numbers will be solve individually on specific column. Now, i need to know how am i going to get the average of 1stAP_TB, 2ndAP_TB, 3rdAP_TB and 4thAP_TB while there are in rows.

Also, there are multiple data that will be save inside the database. I am using C# programming language.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't have any sample because i don't know  how to. The output will be saved inside the database. the output will be saved inside textbox. the above data will be in ROWS. not column.

Comment: your question is little confusing can you elaborate it

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV i want to ask on how am i gonna get the average of  1stAP_TB, 2ndAP_TB, 3rdAP_TB and 4thAP_TB which are in rows.

Comment: what you meant by which are in row?? also 1stAP_TB is a column or a table ??

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV 1stAAP_TB is a column. but i need to get the average in that are save in 4 different column. for example, 90 is save in 1stAP_TB, 88 is save in 2ndAP_TB, 54 is save in 3rdAP_TB and 53 is save in 4thAP_TB.  i need to get the average of 4 numbers.

Comment: select (column1+column2+column3+column4+column5)/5 as average

Answer (score 0):

Try below method

```
create table aveexample
    (a1stAP_TB int,
    a2ndAP_TB int,
    a3rdAP_TB int,
    a4thAP_TB int,
    a1steng_TB int,
    a2ndeng_TB int,
    a3rdeng_TB int,
    a4theng_TB int
    )
```

Sample data

```
insert into aveexample values(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
insert into aveexample values(11,22,33,44,55,66,77,78)
insert into aveexample values(2,3,1,4,10,10,45,5)
```

Method 1

```
select *, (select AVG(totaldata)
from (values(a1stAP_TB),
(a2ndAP_TB),(a3rdAP_TB),(a4thAP_TB),(a1steng_TB),
(a2ndeng_TB),(a3rdeng_TB),(a4theng_TB)) total(totaldata))as average
from aveexample
```

Method 2

```
select ((a1stAP_TB)+
(a2ndAP_TB)+(a3rdAP_TB)+(a4thAP_TB)+(a1steng_TB)+
(a2ndeng_TB)+(a3rdeng_TB)+(a4theng_TB))/8 as Average 
from aveexample
```

Comment: i need to first to save 1 number at a time. so i need to save 4 times, before getting the average. i am not declaring any number.

Comment: i did not get you , please tell me your goal

Comment: Example, i will input first number 2 then save inside the database, then number 3 then save inside the database, then 5 and save it inside the database. then 5 save it inside the database. they are in different columns. so i want to get the average. the numbers is not given, it could be anything.

Comment: what number is not given ? you mean you have dynamic columns ? your goal is little confusing pls provide some sample input and sample output

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give concrete advice given the very limited description in the question, but from the description and comments so far, it seems to me like the database needs to be redesigned to better fit your requirements. First, you have no ID field, so there is no way to differentiate one row from the next. Then, what you are left with is a series of repeated values. The clue here is that you have "1st", "2nd", "3rd" in the column names. That's probably a sign that those columns need to be moved into rows of a related table. It may not instantly seem to be the best approach, but this is called "[First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)" and is a typical best practice with SQL databases. See also [Database Normalization Basics](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/283878).

It seems to me that what you have here is some entity (which you haven't mentioned in your question) that has a number of values associated with it. The 'entity' here should be given a unique ID and then all of the values for that entity stored with its ID.

You might have a table with the following columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyItems (
ID int NOT NULL,
Sequence int NOT NULL,
Value int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_MyValues_ID_Sequence PRIMARY KEY
    (ID,Sequence)
)
```

Note: `ID` + `sequence` forms the unique primary key for the table and makes every row unique. This also lets you keep track of what order the items were added in. This may or may not be important to you but every table should probably have a unique primary key.

Your data table would then look something like this (the example represents two different entities, the first having 4 values and the second having 3 values):

[image: Sample Data]

It's difficult to show a sensible example without knowing more about the application and what it does... but with this table design you have a basis from which to add values one at a time, as you said you needed, and a way to query them back. You can use grouping to produce things like totals and averages, or you can do that in code by iterating over the results of a query or in a LINQ statement.

You can then compute the average for an entity of a given ID using a LINQ query along the lines of:

```cs
var average = MyItems.Where(p=>p.ID == 1).Average(q=>q.Value);
```

As an example of the flexibility of this sort of approach, you could just as easily compute the average of every second value entered across the entire database:

```cs
var averageOfSecondItems = MyItems.Where(p => p.Sequence == 2).Average(q => q.Value);
```

The example I've shown deals with one type of value. In your question it appears that you might have two different types of value. There are several ways you could handle that - for example you could add another column to the table if the values are always entered in pairs, or you could create a second table to hold the separate values. Again, it's hard to make a recommendation based on the limited information given.

If putting your data into First Normal Form seems like a lot of work, then your application might be a better fit for a document database ("NoSQL" database), but that is really a different question. In the question, a SQL database was specified so I've concentrated on that.